# c console programs

Tags: c

I have a *.exe console file.
I enter my inputs, and everything is great.

but when I enter the last input, the command window closes (because the program has ended)
before I can read the last output.

is there a way to run that *.exe file and force it to stay open after the program ends?

note: this is not my program. I can't edit the source code, so I'm not looking for answers like "add while(1) or scanf at the end".

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Sorry for the incorrect close vote and comment (now deleted) I thought I was in another tab...there is a duplicate for this around somewhere, but I'm too lazy to find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just open a command prompt and run it, the way it's meant to be used.

Start -> Run -> cmd.exe

or Win+R -> cmd

Answer (score 3):

Run the program from command prompt (Start-Run-cmd.exe)

Answer (score 2):

Make a batch file (*.bat), with the command you want to execute, followed by pause:

```
myconsoleapplication.exe
pause
```

Save it, and run. The command window wil wait for enter to be pressed before closing.

Answer (score 1):

Run it from the console, or in a batch file.

Start >> Run >> cmd.exe

Then the console window is already open.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
system("pause");
```

At the top of your program, include stdlib.h:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can open a command prompt window and navigate (the `cd` command) to the directory containing the .exe file.  Then, run the program by typing its name.  The window will not close after the program finishes running.

Answer (score 0):

You could execute this program from one of your own, redirecting stdio and adding your own pause after it terminates. I've done this with .NET but assume that it can be done through other means. Of course a batch file, as mentioned already, is wicked simpler.