# Trouble reading .txt file

Tags: c++, file

Hello all I am a very basic programmer and am trying to learn how to make my code read a .txt file but it won't have anything pop up when I try to compile it nothing happens. I get the obvious errors for not using my double values but the .txt file i input with my .cpp file should print a result to the screen. The premise of this project is to write a program that reads in from a file two month names followed by the rainfall amounts(Rainfall.txt) for each month in that span of months. The program should calculate the totals and output the average for each month. I'm very confused why this is not working and would love some constructive and hasty feedback thank you for considering and taking your time.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
int main()

{
string months_one, months_two;
double total=0, average=0;
int counter;

ifstream myfile;
myfile.open("Rainfall.txt");

if ( myfile.fail())
{
    cout << "Error on file open." << endl;
}
else
{
    myfile >> months_one;
    myfile >> months_two;


    }
    cout << months_one << months_two;
    }
```

Comment: And where do you calculate the average?

Comment: Im going to add that in later but for now I am not able to draw information from the .txt file

Comment: So I've reviewed some of your other posts, and "having trouble with output" is a recurring theme.  Maybe if you put exact steps of what you're doing we can help troubleshoot?  Like:  1) In VS (or whatever compiler you're using) click "Build"  2) Click "Debug" and "Start" ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking here... I ran a quick test copying your code as is and it outputs (albeit a bit oddly) two lines of a text file...

When you say "when I try to compile it nothing happens"... you mean you try to compile it and it does not build the binary?

I wonder if you may be running the program, perhaps by double-clicking on the resulting binary, and the command prompt is popping up and going away before you can even see it?  See maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11953364/why-is-the-command-prompt-disappearing-after-loading).

Edit:  Ooops actually maybe [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241435/c-console-programs) is better...

Comment: No when I go to compile it I am supposed to get a result it makes sense it didnt compile right on yours as you didnt have the .txt file i specified in my code in your files or code

Comment: by result i mean an output as in something is supposed to print to the screen and its just a .txt file not a .exe file

Comment: Yes... exactly... I just put a small text file with two lines of text in it, and had it (in the SAME location as my built file) and built the file.  Then, at a command prompt I ran the newly-built binary file, and saw it print the output of my Rainfall.txt file.

Comment: You understand that you have to first COMPILE, and then actually RUN the program, right?  Compiling it simply builds a binary file (.exe if you're on Windows) and then you have to actually run the file.

Comment: yeah i compiled it and debugged it and everything but for some reason I am getting no output at all

Comment: You're not even seeing "Error on file open."?  I got that before I created Rainfall.txt.  When you say "debugged" you mean run through the debugger?  Rainfall.txt must be in same directory that the binary file is in....  I could:  1) copied your code AS IS into a file foo.cpp  2) ran (from VS2008 command prompt) "cl foo.cpp"  3) created Rainfall.txt with two lines: 'hello' and 'there'.  4) From command prompt, typed "foo.exe"    Result: it displayed what was in Rainfall.txt.  I am not sure why you are not seeing the output, even the error message, that I saw.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this very same problem. What I was doing wrong was taking .txt files from a location on my computer and dragging them into my C++ project in Eclipse. The problem was that even though they appeared to be in my "workspace" that actually were not. I had to go /usr/home/workspace (The location of your code may be different) From there, find the project folder you are working on and put you .txt files in there. Then go back to your project in Eclipse, right-click, and "Refresh" your project.

From there the files should appear and your program should run properly.